# Parsing JSON string with different local (no english)

Tags: ios

I got below JSON string, i facing issue parsing because it contains non english local:

> {"error":0,"token":"59188a107d705f8c51585d719769e0642ce98b79d86fdace30dbc58efba301cc","status":"200","messages":[{"update_time":"2012-03-31
>   22:50:13","seq":"497","lng":58.4235,"msg":***"hhhh : ≈∏?≈∏?
>   √ø‚Ñ¢√ø‚Ñ¢√ø√ü≈∏?√ø‚Ñ¢ "***,"lat":23.5866}],"error_msg":""}

i'm trying with below code:

```
NSError* error;
    NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData //1
                                                         options:kNilOptions 
                                                           error:&error];
```

it works fine if it's in English only, how could I parse non english local in JSON.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html):

> The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

Since your string does not appear correctly in Safari, I suspect that it is not encoded in one of these formats. You would need to re-encode your data into a legal JSON encoding.

Comment: Is there is away to parse string without knowing in which encoding it is?

Comment: No. You could use some heuristics to try to determine the encoding (looking for certain patterns that might be likely in one encoding or another), or you could try decoding it with various encodings to see if any of them worked. That could of course lead to errors, since it's possible for the same string to decode different legal ways in different encodings.